# Bootstrap Input Group Addon Floating RIght

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have my input range all in one line and connected but after I added the span part the addon and the last textbox float to the right making them not joined. It works fine on mobile phones but on a normal monitor it has them separated. How can I move the addon and the last textbox next to the first textbox? (The Year and Price Textboxes are examples of my issue)

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is what the Year code looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="tbxBegYear" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Year</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxBegYear" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" MaxLength="4" placeholder="Begin"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxEndYear" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" MaxLength="4" placeholder="End"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This can all depend on your scaffolding. You mention it looks ok on a mobile. You are using col-sm for the grid layout, which defines grid systems mainly for ≥768px and ≥992px. Defining more grid classes may change your layout. Plus it depends on the container these elements are and there widths / grid layout.  As an example, something quick like this - http://www.bootply.com/sYPYqdqk7Y shows fine.

Comment: Yep, agree with @haxtbh. We need more info. With what you've given us it looks fine (see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbwWEJ). Some other style may be throwing this off. Can you create a demo?

Comment: Okay, I see what you guys area saying. I think the issue may be because my textboxes have a max size of 200px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works, so I'm guessing you have some CSS somewhere that we'd need to see to answer the question:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="End"/>
</div>
```